# Error deploying solution using Octopus deploy

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, octopus-deploy, umbraco-ucommerce

I have a web project written in Sitecore 8/uCommerce.  I am using Teamcity to compile and package the project and Octopus deploy to push it out.  When I commit to SVN Teamcity picks up the changes, compiles and packages it up and Octopus deploys it to the Dev environment.  All works well.  However when I try to promote to test I get an error...

> Error running conventions; running failure conventions... Fatal
>   10:24:19 Deployment on the Tentacle failed.

In the project I have a post deploy script (`PostDeploy.ps1`) to remove unwanted config files.  There is only one line...

```
.\DeleteConfig.exe $OctopusEnvironmentName
```

I changed it to this from..

```
.\DeleteConfig.exe $OctopusParameters['Octopus.Environment.Name']
```

Due to an article I read, but this hasn't changed the error.  I have also tried..

```
.\DeleteConfig.exe $OctopusParameters['OctopusEnvironmentName']
```

Again no effect.  If I comment out the line of code I no longer get the error.

I have been trying to fix this for sometime now, read and followed the articles and post I can find on the problem but cannot find the fix.

A slight curveball is that this is the second project we deploy in this way.  The first is also Sitecore/uCommerce and in the `PostDeploy.ps1` the line

```
.\DeleteConfig.exe $OctopusParameters['Octopus.Environment.Name']
```

works perfectly.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the post deploy script an Octopus Powershell step or is it a powershell script when is checked in with your project (into source control)?

Comment: @jammykam Its a file that is part of the project and checked into SVN

Comment: @Fred does that `.\DeleteConfig.exe` file exist? Also as you are trying to run an executable, have you checked that permissions are set correctly on the tentacle? We do something similar in a `PostDeploy.ps1` script, but rather than running an exe file, we just use powershell commands to delete the config files. Maybe that approach would be less problematic

Comment: @RichardSeal Yes the file does exist and permission was one of the things I checked.  They are the same as the other project that works.  Its really odd.  I do like the alternative you have mentioned though so I will see if that makes a difference.  Thanks

Comment: You could as well have a Powershell script as part of Octopus step (post deploy) as an alternative solution. If you use in many places could be abstracted to a `Script modules` section in `Library` menu.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need a post deploy script as there is a community task that cleans up any extra configuration files. It's at https://library.octopusdeploy.com/step-templates/9a2b84db-2940-4d9a-b61f-c82df35cee6c/actiontemplate-file-system-clean-configuration-transforms.
2. If you want to do it your way, I would simply use Poweshell like this:

   Get-ChildItem -Filter Web.*.config l Remove-Item